# Date multiple format conversion in .net framework

Tags: .net, datetime

I need to convert below 2 string formats to DateTime

**"M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm"**

```
     //  CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-IN");
        CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
i)          dt = "07/30/2022 5:30:39 PM";
ii)        // dt = "7/30/2022 5:30:39 PM";
iii)       // var dt = "11-07-2022 09:22";

        DateTime dateValue;
    
        string[] formatStrings = { "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm" };
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dt, formatStrings, enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
            return dateValue;
```

The above code convert only '-' date fornat not '/' format .
Is it possible to convert to '/' date format

```
EXPECTED OUTPUT:  30/07/2022  for i & ii
                  07/11/2022  for iii
```

Comment: I really don't know what `The above code convert only "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm" I have tried many times` means.

Comment: `en-GB` is Great Britain, not US.

Comment: Updated the question.. i need to convert dd/MM/yyyy format

Comment: I have tried en-IN but not works..also tried invarient culture but not works

Comment: When you do `ParseExact` then it must be exact. The location only helps when you use `Parse`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input you have is:

```
"07/30/2022 5:30:39 PM"
```

The pattern you're trying to match that against is:

```
"M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"
```

Note that your input has two digits for the month, but you've told it not to match a leading zero; and that you hour doesn't start with a leading zero but your pattern says it should.

Your pattern should be this:

```
"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"
```

If you try that you'll see it works.

---

Here is working code for all of your inputs:

```
CultureInfo enUS = new("en-US");

string[] dts =
{
    "07/30/2022 5:30:39 PM",
    "7/30/2022 5:30:39 PM",
    "11-07-2022 09:22",
};

string[] formatStrings =
{
    "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
    "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
    "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm"
};

IEnumerable<string> results =
    from dt in dts
    let x = DateTime.TryParseExact(dt, formatStrings, enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dateValue) ? (DateTime?)dateValue : null
    where x != null
    select x.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyy");
```

It produces:

```
30/07/2022
30/07/2022
07/11/2022
```

Comment: string[] formatStrings = { "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm" };  i have tried this also .. it is not convert

Comment: @Ajt, please try single `h`

Comment: Wat did i mistake? Tostring?

Comment: Is it possible to assign value to DateTime  directly without using trstring()

Comment: @Ajt - You didn't get your `formatStrings` correct. You must have them match the input exactly. I explained why they weren't exact in my answer.

Comment: @Ajt - You said you wanted to convert to `dd/MM/yyyy` that format. Only strings are formatted. Dates do not have a format. They are just a number. When you display a date you format it into a string.